# Are there on-line ways to use a block cipher to generate unique $n$ bits that guarantee collision-freeness for $2^n$ times?

Tags: block-cipher, randomness, format-preserving, shuffle

$n$ is a run-time variable chosen each time the user runs the implementation.

One way I can think is to use any block cipher, say AES, as a seeded CSPRNG to randomly shuffle list of numbers $0, 1, \ldots, 2^n-1$.  This way I guarantee collision-freeness up to $2^n$ numbers.  But this approach is too expensive as it will require me to swap $2^n$ numbers.

Another way I can think of is to use the block cipher to generate ciphertext $c = \mathrm{enc}(\mathrm{0x000}\ldots, \mathrm{key})$, where $\mathrm{len}(c) \ge n$.  Then take the 1st $n$ many bits of $c$; let's call it $c_n$.  Then do:  $c_n \oplus 0, c_n \oplus 1, \ldots, c_n \oplus 2^n-1$.  This is efficient, but the problem is that, *i think*, the sequence is not random.  E.g. $c_n \oplus 0$ is generally going to be closer to $c_n \oplus 1$ than, say, $c_n \oplus 100$.

***The question:*** Is any faster approach, where I can use any block cipher for about once only, to generate the next number, such that, as I repeat the process, I get $2^n$ many unique numbers without collisions?

In a sense, I guess I may call it:  an online version of shuffling the numbers $0, 1, \ldots, 2^n-1$, without needing to maintain a list in memory that is $2^n$ long.

Ideally, if the perfect online shuffle is found, it must have this distribution (where $i$ is any number in $\{0, 1, \ldots, 2^n-1\}$ and $N_j$ is a random variable that will take the value of a number in that set in the $j^{th}$ call of the ideal on-line shuffler):

$$\begin{split}
\Pr(N_0 = i) &= 1/2^n \\
\Pr(N_1 = i) &= 1/(2^n - 1) \\
\Pr(N_2 = i) &= 1/(2^n - 2) \\
\vdots & \\
\Pr(N_{2^n-1} = i) &= 1/(2^n - (2^n-1))  = 1\\
\end{split}$$

Comment: Is there some requirement not satisfied by the classical method: enciphering an $n$-bit counter with an $n$-bit block cipher? If so, please state it.

Comment: @fgrieu - Not sure (I guess it's just ignorance).  $n$ in my case is variable (defined at run time by user).  I didn't think of it.  Is ChaCha20 one such algorithms, where I can specify arbitrary blocksize at run time and have the effect above?

Comment: Yeah, I think the key stream generated by counter mode would fit this problem perfectly. If you only have encrypt then it is defined by CTR-mode encryption of all-zero blocks.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Interesting.  Since ChaCha20 internally has 512 byte blocks (at least how implemented usually, e.g. `libsodium`'s), is it possible to optimise the implementation for $n < 512$? such that the sequence is identical but memory/cpu consumption is less than that of a $512$?

Comment: Ah, so the missing requirement is $n$ variable at run time, which forces to use techniques of Format reserving Encryption. Please add that in the question, a range for $n$ (overly large $n$ make little sense, since collisions among independent uniformly random values of $n\ge256$ bit are not observable anyway); and perhaps whatever limit there may be to the number of $n$-bit values an adversary may obtain for a given sequence/key.  Note: ChaCha20 is not a block cipher, much less of variable block width as needed, but it might be used as a building block for one.

Comment: @fgrieu - Thanks!  Sort of off-topic: if I go with ChaCha20, will the 512 be reducible without changing the outcome (if $n < 512$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there on-line ways to use a block cipher to generate unique $n$ bits that guarantee collision-freeness for $2^n$ times?

The obvious way to do this is select a [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) mode of your block cipher, say, [FF1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38G.pdf).  That is a mode that takes an arbitrary length block (in your case, $n$ bits); you would insert the key and encrypt a counter.  With a fixed key (and nonce), the encryption is invertable, and has an output exactly the same length as the input - that gives you precisely what you are asking for.

The only downside I can see is that FF1 may have security issues for truly tiny blocks (in your case, $n \le 6$).  Of course, if the user asks for that small of an $n$, you could fall back on the 'permute the values from 0 to $2^n-1$ strategy...)